# Why update apk failed to install after adding firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, apk

I develop a mobile app and release it. After a while I add Firebase to it without any other changes and sign apk with previous sign key. But if previous apk is installed on Android phone installing update apk cause "The package appears to be corrupt." error.

What is wrong ?

How to find reason of this exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to install APK using ADB as `adb install path/to/your/apk`.

It gives you the error which caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need add -r option to reinstall app if already installed, and try use full path to apk file:
 `adb install -r _HERE_AbsoluteFilePath_`